# Different view levels according to user's role

Tags: javascript, sapui5

in my application, I would like to achieve multi access level for different users depending on their role. I am developing application in openUI5. When I log in to the application I know what roles user have. And according to that roles, I would like to display or hide certain links, tiles, gui components.

Multi access level I mean

1. displaying/hiding gui elements
2. disallowing routing to specified places in application

The point number 2. I have achieved. That's no problem - according to role, I add specific routes to allowed routes.

**I would appreciate an advice for point number 1. what would be the best practice?**

Thank you

Comment: You could use an oData or a JSON Model and bind them to the visible property of your gui elements.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the user's role (a set of authorization rules), you can control the UI in a following ways:

### Huge differences in UI

If the UI should be VERY different depending on user role, it makes sense to implement different set of views created for each role or even apps.

### A few "change points"

In case of not really much differences, you can set up the configurational JSON model, which will contain visibility rules for a certain UI element and you will bind the "visible" property to this configurational model. A set of rules can even be fetched from backend, so it won't be a hardcode on UI, which is pretty handly for customizing reasons.

### User authorization + object state handling

It is also might be the case (very often in my projects), that not only user role has influence on the state of the UI, but the object's state or business logic should define how the UI should look like. I'm talkin about the things like:

- should the filed be displayed or hidden; read-only or editable mode allowed;
- should the action buttons be hidden/visible/clickable and so on;
- should the any UI part be hidden/displayed.

In this case it's easier to let backend control over that by using so-called "**field controls**". They are simple properties in your OData entity type(s) (where needed), which hold the rules for UI.

For example in your entity type you have the field "Amount" and in some cases it should be read-only, while in some others - editable. So you need to add a field-control "UxFc_Amount", it should be integer type and contain 0, 1 or 2:

**0** - means field should be fully hidden

**1** - means field should be read-only

**2** - means field should be editable

Then you bind appropriate properties of control, i.e. for Input control: "editable", "visible", "enabled".

For buttons you can introduce "**action controls**". Let's say you have a "header" object which is bound to the whole page and depending on user's role and the internal object state/status the "Submit" button should be available. So you introduce "UxAc_Submit" property which is a "boolean" (Edm.Boolean) and bind the "**visible**" property of the button to this variable, if it's false - the button will be hidden.

The same approach can be used for showing/hiding the whole sections on UI (for example when you use ObjectPageLayout control).